# IOS-Swift-Is the following singleton implementation really thread-safe in swift?

Tags: swift, thread-safety, singleton

I normally wrote the following implementation of singleton class, I am wondering if this is thread-safe:

```
final class SomeSingleton{ 
   static let sharedInstance = SomeSingleton()
   private init(){} 
}
```

I search a lot of blogs. 
Some say it guarantees thread-safety for the following possible reasons:

1. "by the virtue of let"

I have two confusions about these blogs:

1. When we talk about singleton's thread safety, is it about creating the singleton instance or accessing/modifying the values of the members inside the singleton class?
2. I used the following code to test the thread-safety of singleton. If I am wrong, please point it out.

   ```
   let queue = OperationQueue()

   let op1 = BlockOperation {
       Singleton.sharedInstance.x = 2
       print(Singleton.sharedInstance.x)
   }
   queue.addOperation(op1)

   let op2 = BlockOperation{

       var sum = 0
       for x in 1...99999999{
           sum += x
       }
       Singleton.sharedInstance.x = 3
   }
   queue.addOperation(op2)
   ```

   When the range of the *for* loop is changed, the result printed is different. Can I say the singleton class is not thread safe?

Comment: The static property is thread-safe but property “x” is not.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7 "The lazy initializer for a global variable (also for static members of structs and enums) is run the first time that global is accessed, and is launched as dispatch_once to make sure that the initialization is atomic. This enables a cool way to use dispatch_once in your code: just declare a global variable with an initializer and mark it private."

Comment: See its nothing like thread-safe, static variable means it will initialize only once so you will have only one instance of the class if using sharedInstance property, Note: still you can allocate SomeSingleton class object using -> SomeSingleton() notation.

Comment: @vivekDas the initializer is private how can I allocate another instance in my implementation?

Comment: Yes, if private init you have then you can't allocate another instance, that is right!

Comment: @vivekDas then what do you mean by "Note: still you can allocate SomeSingleton class object using -> SomeSingleton() notation."